# Cascading combo box dynamic update

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a table in SQL Server with contacts. I linked this table to a combobox in a winforms using c#.

When I select a contact in the combo a method fills some textboxes with properties from that contact so user can change what they like, than update (by clicking a button) that contact in db.

One of this contact prop it's a reference key to another table, so instead of textbox I placed a second combobox to select a new value to update the contact prop.

p.s. I have a model for every table (ContactModel.cs, ecc), with prop and ctor's

So the question is: How can I set the combobox.selecteditem (when the user selects a contact) to match the value from the selected contact?

Also, I am using Dapper.

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public int ContactID{ get; set; } // Primary
    // some other props
    public int RefContactCommon { get; set; } // Reference to Common table
}

public class CommonModel
{

    public int CommonID { get; set; } // Primary
    public string CommonName { get; set; } // varchar(32)
}
```

This is how I generally wire up all the combos

```
combo2.ValueMember = "propID";
combo2.DisplayMember = "propName";
combo2.DataSource = SQLHighway.Loadthatprop();
```

Comment: Did you try to set the SelectedValue in the second combo to the current value from the first combo selected object property?

Comment: it's what i will to do but i don't know how. I can't access the obj prop using combo1.selectedItem or combo1.selectedValue or .selectedWhatever

Comment: You need to write an event handler for the SelectedIndexChanged on the first combo. After you have set the various textboxes you can set also the SelectedValue on the second combo.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the `SelectedItem` of the foreign key combobox by casting the item from the main `ComboBox`

```
private void comboBoxObject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBoxForeignKey.SelectedItem = (comboBoxObject.SelectedItem as MainObject)?.ForeignKeyObject;
}
```

EDIT:

You additional code makes the picture different. You don't have a direct foreign key reference to an object, but only an `int RefContactCommon`. In this case you would need to do more work. You would need to pull the object from the second collection and then assign it to the `SelectedItem`

```
private void comboBoxObject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommonModel foreignKeyObject = comboBox2DataSourceCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CommonID == (comboBoxObject.SelectedItem as MainObject)?.RefContactCommon);
    comboBoxForeignKey.SelectedItem = foreignKeyObject;
}
```

Comment: @Befano please post also your model classes. The main object and the foreign key object, with the necessary properties. Then I can also addapt my answer to your proper objects

Comment: Question Updated

Comment: @Befano that makes the picture different. You don't have a direct foreign key reference to an object, but only an **id**. In this case you would need to do more work. You would need to pull the object from the second collection and then assign it to the `SelectedItem`

Comment: comboBox2DataSourceCollection? i can't find a .datasourceCollection

Comment: @Befano this is the collection that you used to assign as `DataSource` to your second `ComboBox`. You should retain the data in a variable, since you load it anyway from DB.